# It looks like not funny -> does it make sense?

Tags: american-english

My friend recommanded some game , so I saw game images 
and I told my friend that it look like not funny?

My friend say what mean???

please correct

Comment: Suggested migration to ell.se

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would more correct to say, "It looks like it's not fun." or "It doesn't look like fun."
If something is fun, that means it is something that is enjoyable or something that makes you happy. Funny is an adjective and refers to something that makes you laugh or that you think is strange.